# Trying to post first question with images

Tags: support, new-users, images

I'm a new poster at Stack Overflow. Well, not yet actually.

In an effort to make my question as clear as possible, I've created an illustration of what I'm trying to accomplish along with an illustration of the problem I am facing. After composing my question and adding my images, I clicked "Post Your Question", and was notified that users without 10 reputation points cannot post images. It was further explained as a spam prevention mechanism.

I clicked "Post Your Question" again, just to see if it might work, and then I was presented with a CAPTCHA (maybe a reCAPTCHA) to verify my alive-ness. I thought perhaps that would have been enough, but I was sent back to the question composition page and supplied with the same message regarding images.

The 10 reputation point requirement seems redundant to me as there is already a CAPTCHA in place, albeit for another purpose. It has been a hindrance to my participation. Though I understand it is not very difficult to attain 10 points, and I probably could illustrate my problem with text characters, this still seems like something that should be rectified.

Comment: Post your question with a textual description of the problem, and give me a link to the image, I'll add it for you. Note that although the question was blocked from the system, uploading the image itself wasn't, so it's easy to get a link to it.

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7ccQQ.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hBOvo.png

I wasn't sure how to privately message you. Thanks!

Oh and here is the URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791541/how-to-semantically-code-an-html-nested-table-that-aligns-and-associates-with

Comment: Pro-tip: If you include a link to your (on-topic, well written, [etc.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)) question, the crowd here at meta are generally happy to look it over and upvote where appropriate which can get you over the new-user hump.

Comment: @EvanDriscoll By my reckoning, you should have enough rep to edit those images into your question now.  Enjoy!

Comment: @Evan I edited in the images, you now need to approve my edit (or two other high rep users). Also there are no private messages on Stack Overflow, all communication is public (and we like it that way).

Comment: @YannisRizos Looks like they've taken care of approval for me. Thank you for helping out. (FYI I dig the publicity factor. More... community-y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design.

As noted in [relevant privilege description](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user):

> **Why are restrictions placed on new users?**
>
> Because we allow participation from anonymous internet users, we must take some precautions to ensure that the rare malicious or spammy anonymous user doesn't ruin the experience for everyone else.
>
> We're sorry that we have to sandbox new users, but the first few upvotes on your questions or answers will quickly elevate you out of it!

Though you're right that a CAPTCHA can also prevent spam, that's only part of the system.  There are also actual humans who post spam and this restriction ensures that they're limited to "[Check out these awesome HATS OF MEAT!!!!111!!1ONE!!!](http://www.hatsofmeat.com/)" instead of a huge honking gif with a similar message.

Comment: I was thinking from the viewpoint of non-human spammers, but I suppose there ARE human spammers as well. Ever ignorant am I!

Comment: @EvanDriscoll Recent examples of "contributions" by anonymous users: [1](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/11573), [2](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/11572), [3](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/11571), [4](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/11569) - Be warned, there's some strong language in all examples. All our restrictions, be it the new user restrictions, or having two people approve edits from low rep users, or whatever is because of such behaviours.

Comment: I didn't realize people could even post without registering. I totally understand.

Answer (score 3):

In general I would suggest putting the links somewhere on the web and add links to them in the question.

Someone will probably come along soon, look at the images and edit the question putting the links as inline images.